# Rave Report (delphi), calculate (in code) vertical element position/size

Tags: delphi, printing

Is it possible (how?) to calculate element size (heigh,width) before printing it?
I'm looking for solution to detect necessity to use (or not) directive NewPage if next component is to big to fixed in actual page.
Exactly I have problem with:

```
  var
  MemoBuf: TMemoBuf;
  begin
    MemoBuf := TMemoBuf.Create;
    MemoBuf.Text:=some_text;
    MemoBuf.PrintStart := 0.2; 
    MemoBuf.PrintEnd := SectionRight;
    //here is the main problem
    PrintMemo(MemoBuf, 0, false);
    MemoBuf.Free;
  end;
```

where I don't know: have I insert "newpage" or not fixed hole MemoBuf in place of page for printing.

All advice will be appreciated.

Comment: You should use `try .. finally` when you dynamically create an object like this. If an exception is raised during printing, you'll have a memory leak because `MemoBuf.Free` won't be reached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution:
It is using MemoBuf.ConstrainHeightLeft method.